# How to open a different url with a new tab and automate login in an angular based app

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular based app and I want to open another URL on a new tab from my app and automate a login. For example my app is www.myapp.com, and it will open www.anotherurl.com/login. Let's say I have both the username and password for www.anotherurl.com/login.

How can I automate the login by populating the form and do the login?

Is this something we can achieve from the client side? or this needs a server side implementation?

Or is this is even possible?

Update:
I have no control over www.anotherurl.com/login by the way. This is just another way of saying I want to open gmail.com with credentials and automate a login instead of me typing the username and password, and pushing the login button myself.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

you can send them along as query parameters, but if you are not using https then they will be sent in the clear. for example:

https://www.anotherurl.com/login?user=bob&pass=secret

then in your controller, if these query params are present then call a `login` method

also worth mentioning that even if its over https the password will be in the user's browser history and thats probably not a good thing either.

Comment: sorry i failed to mention that I have no control over www.anotherurl.com.

Comment: sounds like you need a federated login service